# Remote login database with Devise in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm building an app which holds the User data in a separate (remote) database. How do I make Devise use that database instead of the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an entry to your database.yml for the remote database, then in your User (or w/e your devise model is called) tell it to use the remote entry. So something like.

database.yml

```
remote_development:
  host: replace_with_ip_address_of_remote_db
  #[all the other usual db settings like adapter, username, db name, etc.]

#[don't forget remote_test and remote_production entries]
```

User.rb

```
establish_connection "remote_#{RAILS_ENV}"
```

You may also want to add some caching at the model level to reduce remote database roundtrips.